# IF statement output in bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement, output

When I run this script the first question it asks is "Would you like to use curl? [Y/N]:" to which my reply is often Y or y. However, when I do that the instant output I get is "Unknown!". I'm expecting to see the next question from the code which is "Great, do you want to ignore certificates [Y/N]: "

Can anyone edit my code to make it work as expected? And tell me why?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Build command"

read -r -e -p "Would you like to use curl? [Y/N]: "

curlstring="curl"

if [[ "${input,,}" == "y" ]]; then    
    read -r -e -p "Great, do you want to ignore certificates [Y/N]: " input

    if [[ "$input" == "y" ]]; then
        curlstring=$curlstring" -k"
    else
        curlstring=$curlstring" "
    fi

    echo "$curlstring"    
elif [[ "${input,,}" == "n" ]]; then
    echo "Bye"    
else
    echo "Unknown!"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Hey Aaron, this is Aaron. You should add `input` at the end of your first `read` command as you did in the second so that the `$input` variable you test afterward corresponds to the input of the user.

Comment: Thanks so much Aaron, this solved my issue (new to coding over)

Comment: You're welcome Aaron, glad to help an homonym :) By the way, try executing your scripts with `bash -x <script>` next time, it shows what happens during the program's execution and you would have likely seen that no variable was changed with the read and that you were testing against an unset variable.

Comment: Ahh I see, i'm sure that will come in handy down the line. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is your are *not* actually capturing the user input from the first `read` command, change it,

```
read -r -e -p "Would you like to use curl? [Y/N]: " input
```

Also `bash` is quite sensitive about the constructs used, the line number 15

```
fi echo "$curlstring"
```

will likely throw a ***syntax error*** saying below when you give a `Y` or a `y` as one of the options,

```
Would you like to use curl? [Y/N]: Y
script.sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
script.sh: line 15: `    fi echo "$curlstring"    '
```

change it to separate lines.